# GO store value froom LOOP

Tags: go

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var kata, kosong, kebalikan string

    fmt.Print("Kata :")
    fmt.Scan(&kata)
    panjang := len(kata)
    for i := panjang - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        kebalikan := kosong + fmt.Print(string(kata[i]))
    }
    if kata == kebalikan {
        fmt.Println("\n", true)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("\n", false)
    }
}
```

does anybody know how to store kosong + fmt.Print(string(kata[i])) to kebalikan ? just new in golang
the error is multiple-value fmt.Print() in single-value context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

1. You need to use `fmt.Sprint` instead of `fmt.Print` in your case. The former returns a string, the latter prints it to stdout.
2. Do not use `:` in `kebalikan := kosong + fmt.Print(string(kata[i]))`. You do not want to create a new local variable, instead modify the existing variable.

Here is the fixed code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var kata, kosong, kebalikan string

    fmt.Print("Kata :")
    fmt.Scan(&kata)
    panjang := len(kata)
    for i := panjang - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        kebalikan = kosong + fmt.Sprint(string(kata[i]))
    }
    if kata == kebalikan {
        fmt.Println("\n", true)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("\n", false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason to `Sprint()` a string to a string?

Comment: You're right, a complete oversight on my part. I was very much narrowly focused to fix the issue :facepalm: